# UITableView inside UITableViewCell is a good solution for my issue?

Tags: ios, uitableview

*The idea*:

We have a RSS Feed (like in Instagram let’s say) which consists from posts. A post consist from:
Question (text), user photo, user name and list of answers. Answers can be text or picture. Also there can be different number of answers (from 2 to 6).

Please, refer to the attached concept layout of the above idea for more clarity - https://cs7054.vk.me/c627728/v627728420/ec36/ZxspU4fKVxA.jpg

---

*The Problem*:

I have tried to use tableView in `UITableViewCell` as a subview, but I encounter some issues with this method when filling cells with answers. As I have different number of rows with answers,I need to somehow figure out what post I am filling at the moment and set for it appropriate number of rows with answers.

Also,I was following this tutorial https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/adding-a-uitableview-inside-a-uitableviewcell/  , but there are static number of cells in every post. Also I have to do the same in storyboard but not in xib and storyboard gives me an error

> "The tableViewCellWithTableView outlet from the RMNewsFeedTableVC to the RMNewsFeedCell is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content”.

---

*The Question*:

I would really appreciate if you advise the best practice to implement this feature. I’ve been going through different questions on stack overflow since beginning of previous week, and it seems that there is some solution, however I was not able to find it to the moment. 
Thank you!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEVSY.png

Answer (score 1):

I think best solution will be `UICollectionView`

You can find good tutorials there

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uicollectionview

Or google more.

Another solution - use 6 subview buttons in cell, show them according to answers count, and hide all others